# C# Windows Forms Type Conversion Error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, type-conversion

Right now, I am learning C# from a textbook. In one of the examples in the chapter I'm currently stuck on, Windows Forms, I am instructed to enter the following code to create a simple window:

```
namespace WinForms {

using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class HelloWindowsForms : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;

    public HelloWindowsForms()
    {
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();

        label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8,8);
        label1.Text = "Hello Windows Forms!";
        label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(408,48);
        label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 24f);
        label1.TabIndex = 0;
        label1.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center; //this is the problem

        this.Text = "Hello World";
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5,13);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(426,55);
        this.Controls.Add(label1);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Run(new HelloWindowsForms());
    }
    }
}
```

On the problem line(specified in single line comment) I get this error when running this program:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment' to 'System.Drawing.ContentAlignment'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (CS0266)
```

Other sources online say I need to cast, but I can't figure out what to cast or what to cast it as. I tried skipping ahead and completing the chapter, but I get similar `Cannot implicitly convert type` errors when trying to do all of the examples. Can someone help me figure out how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like Powell/Weeks' book, 2002 vintage.  Based on a very early .NET 1.0 beta.  You are getting out of this what you paid for it, presumably nothing.  Don't waste your (and our) time, it is too valuable, it is teaching heavily outdated concepts.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong enum.  You are using a `System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment` enum when the `TextAlign` property is calling for a `System.Drawing.ContentAlignment` enum.  Try this:

```
label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

Answer (score 0):

I bumped in the same problem and figured this out,

If you are using

> Label

then use this:

`this.Label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;`

I think you are using

> TextBox

Therefore, use:

`this.textbox1.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;`